# Caching effect on CORS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: browser, amazon-s3, webpack, cors, cache-control

The short version of this issue is we are seeing the typical CORS error (`x has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`) however we are absolutely sending the specified headers. The requests are fine to begin with however after n (pattern undetermined) amount of time SOME (no real pattern to this other than it's a random 1 or 2 assets referenced in the html file) requests will suddenly start failing. *On a hard refresh or with disabling cache, the issue is resolved.*

We're wondering how caching may affect CORS in this case? Or if the issue lies elsewhere?

What we see is the asset is loaded fine in the first instance.

Here's a cURL representation of what the browser (**chrome**, not tested elsewhere) sends to the server (**cloudfront in front of s3**):

```
curl -I 'https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/style.allapps.add899080acbbeed5bb6a7301d234b65.css' \
  -H 'Referer: https://lystable.kalohq.ink/projects/2180?edit=true' \
  -H 'Origin: https://lystable.kalohq.ink' \
  -H 'DPR: 2' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gec
```

And the headers in response to this look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 5632
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2017 09:23:04 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Jun 2017 09:16:15 GMT
ETag: "ece4babc2509d989254638493ff4c742"
Cache-Control: max-age=31556926
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Vary: Origin,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method
Age: 3384
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 adc13b6f5827d04caa2efba65479257c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: PcC2qL04aC4DPtNuwCudckVNM3QGhz4jiDL10IDkjIBnCOK3hxoMoQ==
```

After this you can browse the site for a while, refresh a few times and everything is fine and dandy.

But then you might refresh and suddenly you see an error like this in the console:

> *Access to CSS stylesheet at 'https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/style.allapps.add899080acbbeed5bb6a7301d234b65.css' from origin 'https://kalohq.ink' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://kalohq.ink' is therefore not allowed access.*

At this point if you hard-refresh or disable the cache and reload the page everything goes back to working. This is why we're pointing at browser caching behaviour playing with CORS at this point.

The HTML file loading these assets is as follows:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><title>Kalo</title><meta name="description" content="Kalo is used by the best teams on the planet to onboard, manage, and pay their freelancers. "><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><meta http-equiv="Accept-CH" content="Width,DPR,Save-Data"><script>window.performance&&"function"==typeof window.performance.mark&&window.performance.mark("start load bootstrap"),console.log("Kalo v0.214.1 ")</script><script type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous">window.webpackManifest={0:"moment-timezone-data.8189aab661847dea1b73.chunk.js",1:"1.7645e36f0742ed31139b.chunk.js",2:"2.bf0a1c9b400d715e3138.chunk.js",3:"3.d077b7a1cede6f6960e6.chunk.js",4:"4.0bbd51f182d8fa3f4951.chunk.js",5:"5.1dcf124ea7874546fc7a.chunk.js",6:"6.85ee04326ef5cfe2c084.chunk.js",7:"7.cf718eabaa3814fcb47c.chunk.js",8:"8.4c4c5b070e09afe037a1.chunk.js",9:"9.ba3b9a5f540f057fca46.chunk.js",10:"10.3c850061770df8801575.chunk.js",11:"11.df971dd9c4ab435fd421.chunk.js",12:"12.81905afa591a4796dcfc.chunk.js",13:"13.0f78c0c77d45cd79ac26.chunk.js",14:"14.f8f9f24d15e1cc4372a1.chunk.js",15:"15.6badd92530b5da668e98.chunk.js",16:"16.ef87b8dc2f87ca2d40a1.chunk.js",17:"17.bf842b852470057c4f0b.chunk.js",18:"18.f091321e6a0bbf16bf1f.chunk.js",19:"19.0297861a162b49308887.chunk.js",20:"20.7281da4b01eb4eb4bf1f.chunk.js",21:"21.781ca5137a9c76031df2.chunk.js",22:"22.c7dfd45fc0bd41c7618d.chunk.js",23:"23.8c4885794fd57453884a.chunk.js",24:"24.1447090b6f41a311414e.chunk.js",25:"25.021a38e680888fe2ac7e.chunk.js",26:"26.1afe06be0d6164d3409a.chunk.js",27:"27.dc70b696039ad4762a3b.chunk.js",28:"28.8c383709ce92ecae6b0c.chunk.js",29:"29.f594eb538f606ae17c50.chunk.js",30:"30.a2c1dfc70e0fac57b2a4.chunk.js",31:"31.2eaee95b85227b23ccd8.chunk.js",32:"32.528e99c8151fef966483.chunk.js",33:"33.c3b7530ab92bc1280136.chunk.js",34:"34.1eb5635dc498ad450839.chunk.js",35:"35.e71c1e7bc6092ff2a35f.chunk.js",36:"36.0d174c67ddb177944140.chunk.js",37:"37.af1c6ed4cde9120da636.chunk.js",38:"38.fb0dd22a16e7b597ef93.chunk.js",39:"39.c17f705a3438de3dc997.chunk.js",40:"40.d509fa240e2adf2888aa.chunk.js",41:"41.37d2f0e0e06a3c7d816b.chunk.js",42:"42.4febbf78adc3084afec3.chunk.js",43:"43.7aa48b320fcf69adb0a3.chunk.js",44:"44.5e6da9391c7412910447.chunk.js",45:"45.a17d5b7c5e534f260841.chunk.js",46:"46.a1d3a7790959ac892ed0.chunk.js",47:"47.241627b0e5da4ce35606.chunk.js",48:"48.84f9532a64f5a3beb20c.chunk.js",49:"49.f8527afe7cade8fc293a.chunk.js",50:"50.776b466f9019479de8fc.chunk.js",51:"51.ca34827c84d4bcc82079.chunk.js",52:"52.517f4f6c63395646cdd7.chunk.js",53:"53.e3a2103e4151cd13300f.chunk.js",54:"athena.5e6c5b01662cea2c8b1a.chunk.js",55:"hera.b69b80db056ad9c9389f.chunk.js",56:"hermes.29bb236b97c128e8b6ee.chunk.js",57:"iris.834233a6fb064bf576a9.chunk.js",58:"hephaestus.7ac71b3274dda739ba1f.chunk.js",59:"59.ce1aefa687f2ef9c9908.chunk.js",60:"60.5070b818882287dfc402.chunk.js",61:"61.19d5149d0a2bd9ef3c1e.chunk.js",62:"62.d7831f900b939591822e.chunk.js"}</script><link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/favicon.ico" crossorigin="anonymous"><link href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/style.allapps.add899080acbbeed5bb6a7301d234b65.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous"><link href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/style.hermes.689f9795642815d4b8afd20e446a174d.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="preload" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/hermes.29bb236b97c128e8b6ee.js" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="preload" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/style.hermes.689f9795642815d4b8afd20e446a174d.css" as="style" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="preload" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/allapps.commons.8395b1aa9666e3271c40.js" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="preload" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/style.allapps.add899080acbbeed5bb6a7301d234b65.css" as="style" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="preload" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/vendor.83e606c69fc5ae7aeb9b.js" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="preload" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/core/styles/fonts/Fakt-Soft-Pro-SemiBold/FaktSoftPro-SemiBold.1901bce5eea18c64a60693e961585ba1.woff" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="preload" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/core/styles/fonts/Fakt-Soft-Pro-Blond/FaktSoftPro-Blond.4ab21e2be2f31a0ab8d798a9c65f99c1.woff" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/hera.b69b80db056ad9c9389f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/iris.834233a6fb064bf576a9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/athena.5e6c5b01662cea2c8b1a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/moment-timezone-data.8189aab661847dea1b73.chunk.js" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/style.hera.f00a272db8e5756775fb2632e67c1056.css" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/style.iris.1465dc22f4279c748a04c66f3b4494de.css" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/style.athena.6acb14c0d060121364c9a0cf3e6fa0ad.css" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/_/node_modules/@kalo/ui/icon/fonts/MaterialIcons/MaterialIcons-Regular.012cf6a10129e2275d79d6adac7f3b02.woff" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/core/assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.012cf6a10129e2275d79d6adac7f3b02.woff" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/_/node_modules/@kalo/ui/icon/fonts/MaterialIcons/MaterialIcons-Regular.570eb83859dc23dd0eec423a49e147fe.woff2" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/core/assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.570eb83859dc23dd0eec423a49e147fe.woff2" crossorigin="anonymous"></head><body><main id="app"><!--[if lt IE 8]>
  <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an outdated browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]--><noscript>Kalo - Work without boundaries Please wait a moment as we load Kalo. Please make sure you have Javascript enabled to continue. Kalo’s aim is to give companies complete visibility over their external network.</noscript><noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-5XLW75" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript></main><div class="root __splash"><style>html{position:static!important;overflow-y:auto}.root{transition:opacity .35s linear;color:#234957;background-color:#f9fafc;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;opacity:1}.root.exit{opacity:0!important}.navigation{height:60px;background:#fff;border-bottom:1px solid #eceff1}.login{background:#ea5f6e;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;width:50%;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center}@media screen and (max-width:767px){.login{width:100%;right:0}}.hide{display:none!important}.logo{height:107px}</style><div id="navbar" class="navigation hide"></div><div id="login" class="login hide"><div class="logo"><svg width="160" height="70" viewBox="0 0 206 90" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Kalo</title><path fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#fff" d="M17.629 47.172c2.31 0 4.254-.986 6.078-2.833l18.845-19.706c1.824-1.971 3.89-2.957 6.323-2.957 7.294 0 10.212 9.114 5.835 13.55L35.378 54.562l18.724 19.706c3.283 3.571 3.526 8.498.244 12.07-1.46 1.601-3.406 2.464-5.837 2.464-2.552 0-4.62-.986-6.2-2.834L23.707 65.646c-1.7-1.847-3.647-2.832-5.835-2.832h-1.58v17.612c0 4.804-3.405 8.5-8.147 8.5-4.376 0-8.145-3.942-8.145-8.5V8.498C0 3.695 3.647 0 8.145 0c4.5 0 8.147 3.695 8.147 8.498v38.674h1.337zm97.134 29.56c0 2.586-.972 4.433-2.916 5.789-6.566 4.557-15.077 6.773-25.654 6.773-16.656 0-25.653-9.236-25.653-21.676 0-11.455 8.146-20.076 25.045-20.076 3.891 0 8.39.616 13.496 1.848v-3.326c0-6.528-3.283-9.608-11.55-9.608-3.525 0-7.417.74-11.672 2.095-6.686 2.094-11.185-1.11-11.185-6.405 0-3.572 1.823-6.035 5.35-7.513 4.742-2.094 10.698-3.08 17.871-3.08 17.872 0 26.868 8.376 26.868 25.003v30.176zm-15.682-4.68V60.965c-4.378-1.354-8.39-1.97-12.159-1.97-6.443 0-10.577 3.202-10.577 8.006 0 5.296 4.134 8.252 10.942 8.252 4.5 0 8.51-1.11 11.794-3.203zm39.845 8.904c0 4.803-3.405 8.498-8.147 8.498-4.376 0-8.145-3.941-8.145-8.498V9.15c0-4.803 3.647-8.62 8.145-8.62 4.5 0 8.147 3.817 8.147 8.62v71.806zm57.513 1.359c-5.348 4.681-12.035 7.02-20.06 7.02-7.903 0-14.589-2.339-20.06-7.02-5.471-4.68-8.511-10.715-9.118-17.982-.365-5.788-.365-11.7 0-17.612.607-7.391 3.525-13.426 8.996-18.106 5.472-4.68 12.28-7.02 20.183-7.02 8.024 0 14.71 2.34 20.06 7.02 5.349 4.68 8.389 10.715 8.997 18.106.365 5.789.365 11.7 0 17.488-.608 7.391-3.648 13.427-8.998 18.106zm-7.172-33.009c-.363-7.02-5.229-11.946-12.887-11.946-7.417 0-12.402 4.68-13.01 11.946a69.483 69.483 0 0 0 0 12.318c.608 7.266 5.593 11.946 13.01 11.946 7.416 0 12.4-4.68 12.887-11.946a69.326 69.326 0 0 0 0-12.318z"/></svg></div></div><script>"/login"===window.location.pathname&&-1===document.cookie.indexOf("VIEW=")?document.getElementById("login").classList.remove("hide"):document.getElementById("navbar").classList.remove("hide"),document.querySelector(".__splash.root").id="splash"</script></div><script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Symbol,fetch,Intl.~locale.en&amp;unknown=polyfill"></script><script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js" async></script><script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDteWPK1-k97egIjYcX8-Btt8SpRsHit50&libraries=places" async></script><script>!function(e,t,a,n,c,o,s){e.GoogleAnalyticsObject=c,e[c]=e[c]||function(){(e[c].q=e[c].q||[]).push(arguments)},e[c].l=1*new Date,o=t.createElement(a),s=t.getElementsByTagName(a)[0],o.async=1,o.src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js",s.parentNode.insertBefore(o,s)}(window,document,"script",0,"ga"),ga("create","","auto")</script><script>!function(e,t,a,n,g){e[n]=e[n]||[],e[n].push({"gtm.start":(new Date).getTime(),event:"gtm.js"});var m=t.getElementsByTagName(a)[0],r=t.createElement(a);r.async=!0,r.src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-5XLW75",m.parentNode.insertBefore(r,m)}(window,document,"script","dataLayer")</script><script>!function(){function t(){var t=a.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript",t.async=!0,t.src="https://widget.intercom.io/widget/s21m3m5m";var e=a.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];e.parentNode.insertBefore(t,e)}var e=window,n=e.Intercom;if("function"==typeof n)n("reattach_activator"),n("update",intercomSettings);else{var a=document,c=function(){c.c(arguments)};c.q=[],c.c=function(t){c.q.push(t)},e.Intercom=c,e.attachEvent?e.attachEvent("onload",t):e.addEventListener("load",t,!1)}}()</script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/vendor.83e606c69fc5ae7aeb9b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/allapps.commons.8395b1aa9666e3271c40.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/hermes.29bb236b97c128e8b6ee.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></body></html>
```

Something to note here is that all `<script>` and `<link>` tags have `crossorigin="anonymous"`. Also note the `<preload>` and `<prefetch>` tags.

The issue is mostly affecting stylesheets it seems BUT scripts have also been affected in the same manner. Again it's really odd that it seems to pick randomly which assets will break and when. Considering these two facts perhaps it is even based on the reference ordering in the document/load order.

A few final clarifications hopefully to help:

- Assets served from cloudfront in front of s3 (see response headers)
- Not had reports/testing in browsers other than chrome at this point though can hopefully update on that shortly
- All the script and stylesheet assets are preloaded using

Any help or guidance with this issue is going to be hugely appreciated. It's pretty blocking at the moment!

**Update:**

So we have managed to get what appears to be a continuously working build out without any apparent issues. Hard to know for 100% without time due to seemingly sporadic/random nature of the issue. What we changed was the following:

- Bypass Cloudfront to directly reference assets in S3. What could be different?
- Set `access-control-max-age` to `-1` which disables this. We wouldn't expect this to have any effect because this should only (reading spec) affect preflight requests which don't occur for GET requests.
- Remove the preload/prefetch link tags.

We are now doing further testing to try and isolate one or a combo of these as the culprits. We can then dig further into what is happening there.

> Note this *solving* the issue has now been proven incorrect. See *Update 2*.

**Update 2:**

We have had further reports and occurrences in-house of the issue after the previous rollout which we thought bypassed the issue. One effect the previous rollout did have was that the issue is now seen much less frequently. Again a hard refresh fixes everything.

The issue is identical to previously described still and, so far, we have not seen first-hand a failure to load JS since the first occurrence - always seems to be a CSS file failing now.

**Update 3:**

Some pretty important information I didn't mention originally is the change which happened around the time this issue started presenting itself.

Last Monday we released a bundle refactor, powered by [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) which meant assets became shared between deployments. For example if an output file `allapps.commons.HASH123.css` didn't change between release v1 and v2 then the idea is we could leverage browser caching.

What still happens, however, is that the script uploading these assets to S3 *IS* currently dumbly uploading and overriding the original file. We were under the assumption this change would be pretty harmless since the file is the same name and contents but perhaps this has some adverse effect?

Another effect of this release was that now there will be a lot more assets due to aggressive [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx). One thing to note here though is that none of the async chunks seem to suffer from the same problem (they're using jsonp afterall) and the issue is only with those assets reference via `<script>` and `<link>` tags.

You can find the build artifacts of the release PRIOR to the breaking release [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByRPB4t3N6FjMjNId19tR1ItWGM). And find the NEW build artifacts of the current active release showing infrequent issues [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByRPB4t3N6FjZDVJcUJHVXR2azA). You can also find our deploy scripts [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByRPB4t3N6FjN01CSUpIMzhFMFE)

All resources can be found on google drive [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByRPB4t3N6FjZEVSaTZqOUxRZTQ).

**Update 4:**

This issue is still occurring and has now been reported on an async chunk which is loaded on-demand. Looking at the webpack runtime these scripts are loaded by adding a new script tag to the page, again with `crossorigin="anonymous"`.

**Update 5:**

On each build we now use a unique salt (the release version) when hashing the file names. This means no assets are shared between builds. The issue has continued to persist after this release.

**Update 6:**

I've uploaded a [`.har` file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByRPB4t3N6FjdnZ3ZWZBZ0pPdGM) showing this issue occurring over a user session.

Search for the following string `"url": "https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/style.allapps.add899080acbbeed5bb6a7301d234b65.css",` and see the various requests made for this asset. You will see the first few are fine and have the headers you'd the expect. The last occurrence (line 32624) is the one which failed.

```
{
    "startedDateTime": "2017-06-28T09:40:15.534Z",
    "time": 0,
    "request": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/style.allapps.add899080acbbeed5bb6a7301d234b65.css",
      "httpVersion": "unknown",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Referer",
          "value": "https://kalohq.ink/account"
        },
        {
          "name": "Origin",
          "value": "https://kalohq.ink"
        },
        {
          "name": "DPR",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "name": "User-Agent",
          "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
        }
      ],
      "queryString": [],
      "cookies": [],
      "headersSize": -1,
      "bodySize": 0
    },
    "response": {
      "status": 0,
      "statusText": "",
      "httpVersion": "unknown",
      "headers": [],
      "cookies": [],
      "content": {
        "size": 0,
        "mimeType": "x-unknown"
      },
      "redirectURL": "",
      "headersSize": -1,
      "bodySize": -1,
      "_transferSize": 0,
      "_error": ""
    },
    "cache": {},
    "timings": {
      "blocked": -1,
      "dns": -1,
      "connect": -1,
      "send": 0,
      "wait": 0,
      "receive": 0,
      "ssl": -1
    },
    "serverIPAddress": "",
    "pageref": "page_10"
  },
```

**Update 7:**

So last night we pushed a change which removed the usage of the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute *everywhere*. So far we have not seen the issue occur (still waiting given the nature of the issue) but are seeing some interesting and unexpected responses from the requests being made now. Would be great if we could get some clarification on what exactly is happening here. I don't believe we expected removing `crossorigin="anonymous"` to have such an effect or even understand why it was so broken before since our server is setup to send the correct headers AND the `Vary` header.

*Request from cli to s3, with an Origin header, no cors response headers*

```
curl -I 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/olympus.lystable.com/style.allapps.5ebcc4d28ec238a53f46d6c8e12900d1.css' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/59.0.3071.109 Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1' -H 'Referer: https://asos.kalohq.com/categories' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DPR: 1' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H "Origin: https://kalohq.com" --compressed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: kxOvBrYsKyZ42wGgJu8iyRZ8q6j5DHDC6QoK1xn2e8FO1wIEEVkxQ0JvGQTmwrN/Njf8EOlmLrE=
x-amz-request-id: DA8B5488D3A7EF73
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 13:27:47 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 11:30:50 GMT
ETag: "c765a0a215cb4c9a074f22c3863c1223"
Cache-Control: max-age=31556926
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 5887
Server: AmazonS3
```

*Request a moment later from cli again to s3 with just origin header. Now suddenly gives all expected CORS headers back...*

```
curl -H "Origin: https://kalohq.com" -I https://assets-frontend.kalohq.com/style.allapps.5ebcc4d28ec238a53f46d6c8e12900d1.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 5887
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 13:33:09 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Max-Age: -1
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 11:30:50 GMT
ETag: "c765a0a215cb4c9a074f22c3863c1223"
Cache-Control: max-age=31556926
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Vary: Origin,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method
Age: 69
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 a19c66da9b402e0bee3fd29619661850.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 3wQ7Z6EaAcMscGirwsYVi1M_rvoc1fbI034QY4QZd6IqmlRzLRllEg==
```

**Update 8:**

The removal of `crossorigin="anonymous"` tags have resolved the issue. Investigation into why this suddenly started being an issue with this release is ongoing since we had this attribute on script tags *before*.

---

*All resources useful in this investigation can be found on google drive [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByRPB4t3N6FjZEVSaTZqOUxRZTQ).*

Comment: I ran through this CORS cache issue not long ago, I'll try to find back how I solved it for you. 

Meanwhile, as far as I remember, [it's specific to Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409090). Can you confirm this ?

Comment: Can confirm that's what we're seeing @Bigood Chrome only

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems they won't fix this ([see related issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426089#c29)). I'll still try to remember what I did to avoid this though.

Comment: Really appreciate it @Bigood

Comment: Update 7 shows the lack of `Vary` header in the first response.

Comment: Had the same issue and also removing ```crossorigin="anonymous"``` solved it. Thanks!

Comment: It should be mentioned that a good reason to use the `crossorigin` attribute is to be able to send [cross domain script errors](https://blog.bugsnag.com/script-error/) to a third party bug tracker. However, we're experiencing the same issues above.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question in that way, I had the same issue an I found it really helpful to see all your research steps.

Answer (score 49):

https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/style.allapps.add899080acbbeed5bb6a7301d234b65.css only returns CORS headers when an "Origin" header is present (which is sent with a CORS request, but not regular requests).

Here's what happens:

1. User fetches CSS as part of a no-CORS request (eg, `<link rel="stylesheet">`). This caches due to the `Cache-Control` header.
2. User fetches CSS as part of a CORS request. The response comes from the cache.
3. CORS check fails, no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

The server is at fault here, it should use the `Vary` header to indicate its response changes depending on the `Origin` header (and others). It sends this header in response to CORS requests, but it should send it in response to non-CORS requests too.

Chrome is somewhat at fault here, as it should use the credentials mode of the request as part of the caching key, so a non-credentialed request (such as those sent by `fetch()`) shouldn't match items in the cache that were requested with credentials. I think there are other browsers that behave like Chrome here, but Firefox doesn't.

However, since you're using a CDN, you can't rely on browsers to get this right, as the caching may still happen at the CDN. Adding the correct `Vary` header is the right fix.

tl;dr: Add the following header to *all* of your responses that support CORS:

```
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
```

Comment: Cheers for the response! Really appreciate the help. There's a few things here that aren't quite adding up though at a glance so would be good to try and clarify.

When originally testing we do have the `Vary` header set in responses from the CDN (copied headers in OP). We've also now bypassed the CDN and have the same issue occurring. Currently verifying the headers being sent directly from S3.

Comment: Also wondering what your expected impact be from removing the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute from our scripts and links? We did this yesterday evening and have not seen the issue since.

Comment: Removing `crossorigin="anonymous"` makes it a no-cors request, so it would work with or without CORS headers. However, it would cache the version without CORS headers, so subsequent CORS requests to the same URL would fail.

Comment: Right seems to be becoming a little clearer now. So Cloudfront seems to set the vary header correctly but not s3. I'm wondering now why this was a) still broken when we were pointing at cloudfront which does send this header and b) why this suddenly broke with our release given that we were already using crossorigin="anonymous" on our script assets and pointing at s3.

Comment: Can you give me a URL that sets the header correctly? https://assets-frontend.kalohq.ink/style.allapps.add899080acbbeed5bb6a7301d234b65.css doesn't

Comment: Just got this report from someone helping me investigate this on the team.

We only allow the GET method in our CORS configuration, and we think CF is being unreliable as to which HTTP method is being used, Particularly since we are doing a HEAD request to CF and it returns us the CORS headers, which it shouldn't (???). So if you're not receiving the CORS headers, it's possible CF was being flakey, or maybe using the wrong method?

Investigation continuing...

Comment: The problem seems really easy to replicate. The CORS headers aren't being sent unless the origin header is present, but the response does not vary on origin. The solution is to vary on origin. Am I missing something?

Comment: That may be one way to replicate but we're trying to confirm exactly how this has happened. Until then I can't confirm any solution or problem. You can see in our original report that the headers do (did??) contain a Vary header. So we're trying to work out why exactly that is not the case as you say and why there would even be requests sent which would not get cors headers back.

Comment: Should the Vary header be seen on the responses to the non-cors request or just the cors request? If this is the problem then we need to investigate why this isn't happening/why this suddenly stopped happening. We touched nothing in our cloudfront/S3 configuration around this release so it's super odd that behaviour has suddenly changed. Note script tags always had the crossorigin attribute long before this issue started occuring.

Comment: The `Vary: Origin` header should be seen on any response that changes its content based on the content (or absence) of the `Origin` header, so it should be on all responses in this case. I say this in the answer above, twice.

Comment: Forgive me for trying to fully understand the full series of changes that has lead to the issue. As I said our configurations have not changed and there's still no explanation for why non-cors requests are even being made by the browser. It looks like the `Vary: Origin` is probably the fault, so thanks for that, but there are still many surrounding conditions to be looked at (ie. what on earth changed?).

Comment: This answer helped me resolve our cache\CORS issue.  Our scenario involves .com.au and .co.nz versions of our Web UI.  We started using ResponseCache in ASP.NET Core.  But we didn't use 'VaryByHeader = "Origin"' (which creates the Vary header). So cache entries were being returned with the wrong Access-Control-Allow-Origin value.Problem solved.

Comment: @ChrisPearce I believe I am having this similar issue. I confirmed with aws support that my requests were received with no origin header, despite seeing them in chrome network tab sent out with the origin header. it seems chrome can strip it with site-isolation. https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation

Comment: I've posted a thread on the AWS S3 forums, because it's the S3 managed CORS implementation that is broken here, by not returning a `Vary: Origin` header on non-CORS requests: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=342401&tstart=0 - I think this has always been broken on S3's side.

Comment: One thing that is unclear to me, is how would the same asset be requested in non-CORS and CORS way? We are experiencing this exact same issue as well and there is only a single way that asset is being requested: via script tag.

Comment: @Lokua there are many APIs that allow a resource to be fetched without CORS, such as `<img>`, `<style>`, `<script>`, `fetch(url, { mode: 'no-cors' })`.

Comment: To complicate matters further, some Web caches ({cough} Cloudflare {cough}) don't necessarily honour the `Vary` header.

Comment: Also, now that Private Network Access is being implemented in Chromium, if some Web caches cache your preflight responses, you should also list `Access-Control-Request-Private-Network` in the `Vary` header.

Comment: @Lokua Not to mention that someone might request the asset in question as a top-level navigation or using something like `curl`.

Answer (score 11):

We experienced the same problem when migrating our JS to Webpack.

Our setup is similar:

- assets are uploaded to an S3 bucket during deployment
- the bucket is set as the Cloudfront origin

When migrating to Webpack, we wanted to take advantage of JS sourcemaps for better error reporting to Airbrake.
To allow errors to be catched properly, the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute had to be set on the script tags.
The reason why is explained here:
https://blog.sentry.io/2016/05/17/what-is-script-error.html

Part of the problem was that CORS response headers were sometimes returned, sometimes not, triggering a CORS errror in the browser.
Cloudfront servers were caching the response with OR without the CORS headers, depending on the first client request making a Miss request.

So two possible outcomes:

1. First client does not send the Origin request header => Cloudfront server caches the response without CORS headers.
2. First client sends the Origin request header => Cloudfront server caches the response without CORS headers.

This made the problem look like it was random, but it was just a matter of race condition (how the first client made the request) and different headers cached on different Cloudfront servers: timing and location dependent.
Add to that the fact that browsers might cache these wrong headers...

So you need to properly configure Cloudront's distribution behavior to:

- allow and cache preflight (OPTIONS) requests
- base the cache on CORS request headers (Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method)

Here is the configuration that solved our problem.

S3 bucket / Permissions / CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>300</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Cloudfront distribution / Edit Behavior:

[image]

---

We now experience a problem similar to yours, as we just migrated our CSS to Webpack. We are experiencing even more sporadic CORS errors for CSS files.
We are trying to remove the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute on `<link rel="stylesheet" />` tags since we don't need error tracking for CSS files.

Comment: Are you finally using `crossorigin="anonymous"` for scripts? I am accessing my files directly from s3 and still, I can reproduce the error on chrome. How I reproduce it: 1. Incognito window; 2. Go to script from s3; 3. Open the page that is using the script - error in the console.

Comment: Same issue, good fix here. With CORS being origin specific, you need the cache to take those factors into account. Adding the whitelist for these headers, specifically Origin, will make the "randomness" of this problem go away. Thanks lakim.

Comment: Caching OPTIONS headers throws webpack bundle errors.

Answer (score 4):

I can shed a little light to how it happened with us. Azure CDN (which we use) does not support Vary: headers right now. So far so bad. But now we use  the script crossorigin attribute which - and thats the interesting thing - is not supported by some browsers.

If now such browser comes to our site, it does not send origin: because it does not understand the "crossorigin" attribute. If later another one comes who understands it, it will send origin: -> CORS Error because first response is cached.

Ugly.

Comment: Even using the `crossorigin` attribute (a hack, if you ask me) doesn't fully protect you. A single `no-cors` request sent at the right time (possibly by an attacker and not necessarily from a browser) could poison the cache.

Answer (score 3):

I want to share that we were having the same issue, but in this case, specifically preloading some fonts.
We noticed that the combination of S3, CloudFront, and Safari was killing us, so we decided to remove `preload` and `crossorigin="anonymous"`.

We were trying to do this:

`<link rel="preload" href="<zzz.cloudfrontUrl.com>" as="font" crossOrigin="anonymous" />`

But safari somehow corrupted the cache and it was giving `not allowed access-control-allow-origin` but only sometimes.

Our assumption there is that maybe there is a problem between safari and preload fonts from maybe any CDN and the `crossOrigin="anonymous"` (which is [required](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#font-fetching-requirements)).

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the CROS configuration has been set in the S3 already, these two points below can make sure that the video will be always loaded on the browser.

1. Add crossorigin=”anonymous” on the  tag
2. Add the "?q=#{Time.now.to_i}" at the end of the S3 URLs

HAML + Ruby code will look something like this.

```
    %video{controls: "", controlslist: "nodownload", crossorigin: 'anonymous'}
     %source{src: "#{s3_url}?q=#{Time.now.to_i}", type: "video/mp4"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem here is how I solved it.
Added Corsrule for wildcard domain(you can choose you origin domain)

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Then go to

```
CloudFront Distribution > Origin and Origin Groups > Edit Origin
```

In your "Origin Custom Headers" fill "Header Name" value "origin" and "Value" to "https://www.yourorigindomain.com"

When you click on `info icon` in the right of `Origin Custom Headers` you will see the message:

> All custom header keys and values you specify here will be included in every >request to this origin. If a header was already supplied in the client request, it is overridden.

So cloudfront add origin header in every request it made to s3 bucket, wheather you pass it from client or not and cache response the headers.

You can check `access-control-allow-origin: *` in response header using

```
`curl -i https://cloufrontdistributiondomain.com/example.png`
```

i.e without passing the host.

Answer (score 1):

When using the Azure CDN, Vary headers are ignored for the cached content, which means Azure only keeps one copy per value of the Accept-Encoding header. This of course introduces issues with CORS.

In order to avoid such issues, the workaround can be to rely on the rules engine and to force the headers:

- Global rule:

  - Overwrite `Vary` response header with value: `Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Accept-Encoding`
  - Overwrite `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header with value: `https://<your domain>`
  - Delete `Server` response header
- Create additional rules for each potential Origin:

  - `If Request Header Origin Equals ...`
  - The response headers should be defined in a similar way to the global rule

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation. And I want to document my debugging process to help more people.

We are building an online image editor. Because we need to export canvas as an image, we need to handle cors for images properly (with crossOrigin: "anonymous").

Similar to the PO, our images are hosted on s3 with cloudfront as the CDN. I noticed the same cors error as that of the question.

> Related Details: both the s3 bucket and the cloudfront CDN had been
> running for a while without the headers:
>
> access-control-allow-origin: *
>
> access-control-allow-methods: PUT, POST, DELETE, GET
>
> The headers were only added recently by following:
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html
> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error/

The issue was very strange to me, because I was pretty sure I set s3 and cloudfront properly to return the headers. I could confirm it with curl, by passing an "Origin".

So my initial guess was that this was a chrome bug.

My friends and I tried different environments, the issue can't be reproduced consistently. Here is the summary:

- Ubuntu 1 + chrome : repro
- Ubuntu 1 + firefox : no repro
- Mac 1 + chrome : repro
- Mac 1 + safari : repro
- Mac 2 + chrome : no repro
- Mac 3 + chrome : no repro

Our chrome version is the same 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Another strange thing was that the issue would be gone randomly while I was trying to debug the issue for no reason. However, the issue would come back next day.

I suspected browser cache at first. I tried clearing cache / hard reload, incognito mode, and a completely fresh chrome session, using:

> google-chrome  --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp

They couldn't resolve the issue.

So the key question to ask was if this is an AWS issue or this is a chrome issue.

Although chrome's devtool did show that the headers didn't present,

> access-control-allow-origin: *
>
> access-control-allow-methods: PUT, POST, DELETE, GET

given the strangeness of this issue and the opposite fact the curl command had told me, I couldn't trust chrome's devtool.

Plus, I also tried right clicking in chrome devtool's network panel over the failed image and choosing "copy as curl", and pasting that curl command line directly into a terminal, and the issue wasn't there either. The headers were simply returned.

Because the image is served by cloudfront with https, I didn't know how to intercept https traffic using wire shark. But I found chrome's network dump function:

> chrome://net-export/

> Later, I noticed that cloudfront has an option to serve using http. That could be an easier way to debug this issue.

And was able to capture the raw traffic:

[image]

Now it is very clear that AWS didn't return the right headers.

I tried immediately with curl with the "Origin" header:

> curl -v -H "origin: http://localhost:9003" https://xxxxx.cloudfront.net/xxxxx.jpg

The headers were returned.

[image]

Notice that in addition to the "Origin" header, chrome sends a lot more headers to the cloudfront endpoint. So I asked if I can reproduce the issue with curl by sending exactly the same headers:

> curl -v -H "pragma: no-cache" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"" -H "origin: http://localhost:9003" -H "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0" -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" -H "accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8" -H "sec-fetch-site: cross-site" -H "sec-fetch-mode: cors" -H "sec-fetch-dest: image" -H "referer: http://localhost:9003/" -H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6" https://xxx.cloudfront.net/xxx/xxx.jpg

[image]

And indeed, if I serve exactly the same headers to cloudfront, I can reproduce the issue with curl too. Most importantly, notice that, when the issue reproduces, there is a x-cache header says "cache hit", whereas when it doesn't reproduce, the same header carries "cache miss".

So, what if I clear the cloudfront cache? I actually tried this first time I saw the bug. I did it by invalidating only the path of the problematic image. But this time, I wanted to [invalidate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) the entire cloudfront cache for that s3 bucket.

After that, I tried again with the same curl command line, and it worked!

[image]

Notice that not only the headers were returned, it also said "cache miss".

So here is my conclusion / learning:

1. Looks like cloudfront does caching not only based on the content itself, but also based on request headers. Different headers will result in different caching behavior and thus different returned data.
2. The reproducible chrome might send different headers than those browsers that didn't reproduce the issue. Essentially they were reading from different caches.
3. The request headers as shown and copied by the chrome devtool is not trust worthy.
4. chrome://net-export/ is an awesome tool.

At this point, I'm 95% sure this is due to cloudfront caching behavior / stale data / headers. But given the intermittency of the issue, I will need to keep observing for a while to be sure.

**Update 1:**

Unfortunately, I checked the next day, the issue just came back:

[image]

I feel that this is cloudfront's bug.

Comment: Hello, do you have any further updates on this issue? I am struggling for the last days with this same kinda behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Five years later I stumbled over this Post having a JavaScript image loading issue with CORS on S3 on Safari. The solution, in my case, was inbelievable:

This code works:

```
image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
image.src = resultSrc;
```

This code does not:

```
image.src = resultSrc;
image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
```

In fact, safari loads the picture on the first line, without CORS headers, and puts in into the cache.
The he loads the image AGAIN, on the second line, with CORS headers, and correctly uses it (on the first request). ON second request, result comes from cache and fails.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the issue with the same setup using CloudFront + S3 serving files from another domain (CORS required).

For me, the CORS issue occurred for the most recent added SVG for unknown reasons (we have multiple SVG's used by CSS, which works fine). Our app is build using Webpack + Module federation which means the app shell handles the injection of CSS.

I used the `chrome://net-export/` as mentioned above (GREAT tool, thanks!) to investigate the headers returned by CF/S3 and the `access-control-allow-origin` header was not included in the response for this specific file. The CORS issue now makes sense but why is CF/S3 not returning the CORS headers in the response?

**Solution**
Except adding CORS settings to S3 we added the `Origin` header to CloudFront under Behaviours/Cache key and origin requests/Legacy cache settings/headers where you can include custom headers.

> Suppose the server sends a response with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin value with an explicit origin (rather than the "*" wildcard). In that case, the response should also include a Vary response header with the value Origin — to indicate to browsers that server responses can differ based on the value of the Origin request header. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#cors_and_caching

As I understand from above the CF setting should not be required when using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header. Anyway, now the CORS headers are included in the response together with the `Vary: Origin` header and it works.

Question still exist why this issue was introduced to this specific file...